# Draw image inside a View without subclassing

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-canvas, android-bitmap

Can I draw a image inside a view without subclassing ? I have tried:

```
TextView texto = (TextView) viewGroup.findViewWithTag("text");
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_lanc);
Bitmap b2 = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b2);
c.drawBitmap(b, 1, 1, p);
textView.draw(c);
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that directly -- calling `draw(Canvas)` on a view will cause *that View* to perform its drawing commands into the canvas. So in your case that would draw the TextView onto the Canvas you provided (not the other way around).

If you needed to do so, you could set a subclass of drawable on the view which does custom drawing itself, and then *that* would draw within the View's canvas, but whatever you're trying to do here, there's likely an easier way. Without knowing more about your requirements it's impossible to say.

Comment: I'm trying to put a icon inside a textview who is already inside a gridview, and when the adapter is calling getview I'll draw depending of database field status value.

Comment: Why don't you just use a FrameLayout containing a TextView and ImageView?

Comment: And also, why can't you subclass?

Comment: If I can do whitout extend a class my maintenance on this code is lower, and is more easier to reuse the code

Comment: Fair enough, I suppose. I'd go with a FrameLayout with ImageView and TextView as children, and just inflate that in your adapter -- assigning the image based on the database value.

Comment: I'll have to do this, but would be easier if had a another way

Answer (score 0):

Drawing does not work like that. The textview's draw() method will be called by android, with a canvas instance provided by the system. When you call it yourself with a canvas that you created, the textview is going to draw itself on your canvas instance, but that has nothing to do with what appears on the screen.

Comment: But have a way to do without subclassing?